kivy file produces blank screen
when I try to set up screen navigation, It produces blank screen without error.
my approach is to execute every line I write
I am expecting a label and an image
Can anyone point out what is wrong with this code. any help will be appreciated
here is my code
main.py
import kivy


from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen



kv = Builder.load_file("outer.kv")

class Firstwindow(Screen):
    pass
class Secondwindow(Screen):
    pass
class Thirdwindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def screen_manager_method(self):
        print('Hello from screen manager')
class CrashCourse(App):
    def build(self):
        
        return kv
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CrashCourse().run()




outer.kv

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

<Firstwindow>:
    name: "home_screen"
    id: home_screen
    Label:
        text:"Enter your name bellow"
    Image:
        source:"down.jpg"
<Secondwindow>:
    name: "menu_screen"
    id: menu_screen
<Thirdwindow>:
    name: "game_screen"
    id: game_screen


When you execute:
kv = Builder.load_file("outer.kv")

the Builder creates a ScreenManager and returns that as kv. The other parts of the kv file result in rules being loaded. Those rules describe how the Screens should be built, but they do not build any Screens. Try replacing:
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

with:
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    Firstwindow:
    Secondwindow:
    Thirdwindow:

This should result in a ScreenManager with three Screens. See the documentation.
